# How to remove html tag from webpage with some other text?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tampermonkey

I'm writing a simple parser for one site and I'm novice. However, that website has [WBR HTML-tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_wbr.asp) inside links. For example, links look like this: 
`<a href="www.example1.com">[The Aven"<wbr></wbr>"gers [720p, DVDRIP]</a>
 <a href="www.example2.com"><[Home alo"<wbr></wbr>"ne [1080p, BDRIP]</a>`

And I need to remove `"<wbr></wbr>"` text. 
I've managed to remove wbr tag with this Tampermonkey script:

```
del = document.getElementsByTagName("wbr");
 if (del.length > 0) {
  for (i = 0, j = del.length; i < j; i++) {
   del[i].parentNode.removeChild(del[i]);
 }
}
```

But I still can't remove quotes, so my new text looks like this:

```
<a href="www.example1.com">[The Aven""gers [720p, DVDRIP]</a>
<a href="www.example2.com"><[Home alo""ne [1080p, BDRIP]</a>
```

And my parser doesn't work. I've tried searching for function to select text, not HTML-tag, but can't find it. Could you help me to modify this script? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to [The Aven"<wbr></wbr>"gers [720p, DVDRIP] as a string??

Comment: Sorry, I can't correctly answer to your question. I have my own Google Chrome extension (which does the parsing) and Tampermonkey extension to work with DOM. I'm pretty noobish in such things.

Comment: your question is not clear, is [The Aven"<wbr></wbr>"gers [720p, DVDRIP] placed somewhere inside the document body?

Comment: like document.body.innerHTML = [The Aven"<wbr></wbr>"gers [720p, DVDRIP] and you want to remove "<wbr></wbr>" from it?

Comment: I've edited my question. That website is torrent-tracker and I parse link text to find necessary film or films only in 1080p

Comment: check my answer and working fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the **wbr** tag, you can remove the quotes by using javascript's replace() functions as:

```
del = document.getElementsByTagName("wbr");
if (del.length > 0) {
   for (i = 0, j = del.length; i < j; i++) {
      var parentElement = del[i].parentNode;
      parentElement.removeChild(del[i]);
      parentElement.text().replace(/"/g, '');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is quite confusing but running it on Fiddle makes it clear, you need to remove only the quotes from the html body and that should do the work:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/"/g, '');
```

See the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ekgycftt/2/). Let me know if this is what you were looking for